# centering and making responsive a blockquote element

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, blockquote

Can somebody please show me how to make a quote that I amu sing on my website both centered and responsive so it gets smaller as the browser window does staying centered, but also so it is centered, just smaller on mobile devices.

Thank you

***CSS***

```
 blockquote {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    left:27%;
}

blockquote p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
    content: "“";
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: "Georgia", Serif;
    color: #28B701;
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: 5px;
}

cite {
    float: right;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

blockquote:after {
    content: "”";
    right: -30px;
    left: auto;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<blockquote><p style="color:#666;">Socrates said, “Know thyself.” I say, “Know thy users.” They don’t think like you do.</p><cite>- Joshua Brewer</cite></blockquote></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `blockquote` is `inline-block` you can center it with `text-align:center` on the parent.

Remove the `left` statement as it's not required.

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
blockquote {
     color: black;
     position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 0 5px;
     margin: 0px auto;
 }
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
blockquote {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
blockquote p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
  content: "“";
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: "Georgia", Serif;
  color: #28B701;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  top: 5px;
}
cite {
  float: right;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
blockquote:after {
  content: "”";
  right: -30px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p style="color:#666;">Socrates said, “Know thyself.” I say, “Know thy users.” They don’t think like you do.</p><cite>- Joshua Brewer</cite>

</blockquote>
```

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D thanks so much, but now that is aligned my divs do not look aligned, how to align them central too? sorry for asking another question but I can't wait an hour and a half to post again haha :)

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to wait as without the the code for the rest of the page it's hard to help. What you **could** do, instead of putting `text-align` on the `body` is wrap the `blockquote` in a div and put the `text-align` on that.

Comment: **Don't do that.** You're changing the question and possibly invalidating all the previous answers. Please remove all that extra detail and code and wait to post a new separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Please see snippet and let me know if issue is still there.

```css
blockquote{
    display: block;
    max-width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    content:"“";
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family:"Georgia", Serif;
    color: #28B701;
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: 5px;
}
blockquote:after {
    content:"”";
    right: -30px;
    left: auto;
}

cite {
    float: right;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
    <p style="color:#666;">Socrates said, “Know thyself.” I say, “Know thy users.” They don’t think like you do.</p>
    <cite>- Joshua Brewer</cite>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```
blockquote{
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Hi @amine250 thanks so much, but now that is aligned my divs do not look aligned, how to align them central too? sorry for asking another question but I can't wait an hour and a half to post again haha :)

Comment: Just resize your divs using percentages (%).

Answer (score 0):

```
blockquote {
    width: 100%;
}

blockquote p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
    content: "“";
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: "Georgia", Serif;
    color: #28B701;
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: 5px;
}

cite {
    float: right;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

blockquote:after {
    content: "”";
    right: -30px;
    left: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
    blockquote {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mike86 thanks so much, but now that is aligned my divs do not look aligned, how to align them central too? sorry for asking another question but I can't wait an hour and a half to post again haha :)

Comment: can you paste all of your code i cant see your antohers divs